# ClassNotFound exception while executing Java AnnotationProcessor

Tags: java, annotations

I wrote a simple annotation and an AnnotationProcessor to process the annotation.

The annotation has a single value: it should be the name of an existing interface (with package).

The annotation processor should retrieve the value of the annotation, retrieve the Class object of the interface and finally should print all method declared in the interface.

Example:
this is my annotation

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)
public @interface MyAnnotation{
    public String interfaceName();
}
```

and this is the annotated class:

```
@MyAnnotation(interfaceName = "java.lang.CharSequence")
public class Example{}
```

my processor looks like

```
[...]
public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment env) {

    for (TypeElement te : annotations) {

        for(Element e : env.getElementsAnnotatedWith(te)) {

            MyAnnotation myAnnotation = e.getAnnotation(MyAnnotation.class);
            String iName = myAnnotation.interfaceName();
            Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(iName);
            // use reflection to cycle through methods and prints them
            [...]
        }
    }
```

now this works fine if I configure an interface like java.lang.CharSequence as the interfaceName of MyAnnotation;

however, if I configure as interfaceName an interface located in a .jar file (added in the buildpath of the project), I obtain a ClassNotFoundException when I try to do the Class.forName(...) statement.

Any thoughts?

Thank you,
cheers

Comment: It may be an issue with the way annotation processing works. Does using [`Elements#getTypeElement(CharSequence)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/lang/model/util/Elements.html#getTypeElement(java.lang.CharSequence)) return a non-null `TypeElement`?

Comment: Hi Slaw, thank you for the response.

I did

TypeElement typeElement = this.processingEnv.getElementUtils().getTypeElement(myAnnotation.interfaceName());

and typeElement is not null.

Comment: In that case, you may be better off accessing information about a class through the annotation processing API (i.e. via the `TypeElement`).

Comment: Hi Slaw, yeah I tried to use that API, but I didn't find any method to read return type or parameter list of a method. Using Java reflection, instead, it was very easy...

Comment: To determine the parameter types and return type of a method with the annotation processor API you need to get the appropriate [`ExecutableElement`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/lang/model/element/ExecutableElement.html). Check out the methods of the [`ElementFilter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/lang/model/util/ElementFilter.html) class. Note, however, that I'm not saying you _have_ to use the annotation processor API in this case.

Comment: Hi Slaw, thank you again! Yeah the ExecutableElement was the thing I was looking at yesterday. I'm doing some experiment with annotations, so I would like to try all possible way to do a thing like this ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a typical ClassLoader issue. You're trying to find a class which was not loaded by the current class loader, so a `ClassNotFoundException` is thrown.

The [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) for `java.lang.Class` defines the method `Class.forName(className)` as:

> Returns the Class object associated with the class or interface with the given string name. Invoking this method is equivalent to `Class.forName(className, true, currentLoader)` where *currentLoader* denotes the defining class loader of the current class.

So, this method call will try to look up the specified class in the current class loader context. The interface you are trying to find has not been loaded by this classloader, so a `ClassNotFoundException` is thrown.

If the `.jar` file is on the classpath of your application, you can simply use the system classloader instead, like so...

```
ClassLoader systemClassLoader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassloader();
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(className, true, systemClassLoader)
```

...But if your `.jar` file is located elsewhere, and has not been loaded yet, you're going to need to load it accordingly:

```
ClassLoader urlClassLoader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{new URL("path/to/file.jar")});
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(className, true, urlClassLoader)
```

Et voilà!

Comment: Hi Daniel and thank you for the response.

Ok, it's clear the issue with the Class Loader, so I changed the line of code as u suggested in 

Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(className, true, ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());

However, the problem is still there. Maybe the problem is here:

"If the .jar file is on the classpath of your application, you can simply use the system classloader "

I'm using Eclipse as IDE, and I added the .jar to the "buildpath", not to the "classpath" (idk the difference)...

Comment: I tried with URLClassLoader and it found the class :)

However, I didn't understand why the SystemClassLoader cannot find it, the .jar is in the buildpath of the project...

Comment: @user1561017 It's a little confusing, allow me to explain. The buildpath and the classpath are two seperate things. Eclipse uses the buildpath to resolve classes inside the IDE. The buildpath is used for compilation, and provides the IDE with rich functionality. It is the classpath that matters at runtime; the classpath is what is used to resolve the loaded `.class` files inside the JVM. The JVM is effectively ignorant to the contents of the Eclipse buildpath. It cares only about the classpath.

Comment: Hi Daniel, thank you again for the explanation. However, this opens another question :) How can I add a given jar to the "classpath" of a project using Eclipse? I can find only the option to add a jar to the "buildpath"... thank you very much